# Why isn't $F_{X}^{-1}(U) \sim F_{X}(x) $?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, finance

In the following passage I am having difficulty understanding we don't have $F_{X}^{-1}(U) \sim F_{X}(x)$?
I also want to ask why is the uniform distribution so involved in simulating random variables?

[image]

Comment: $F_X^{\,}(x)$ takes values in $[0,1]$ while $F_X^{-1}(U)$ can presumably take other values here.   If $\sim$ means has the same distribution then here they you have $U \sim F_X^{\,}(X)$ as well as $X \sim F_X^{-1}(U)$ and it is the latter which lets you simulate $X$ with a uniform random variable and the quantile function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_X(x)$ is not a random variable, so we can't say that it is "distributed equivalently" to a random variable. In fact, $F_X^{-1}(U) \sim X$ means that the random variable $Y = F_X^{-1}(U)$, the result of applying the inverse of $X$'s c.d.f. to the uniform distribution $U$, is distributed equivalently to $X$. That is, the c.d.f. of $F_X^{-1}(U)$ is $F_X(x)$.

The uniform distribution comes up so often in simulating random variables exactly because of the given theorem. For any random variable, if you can invert its c.d.f. and sample from a uniform distribution, the you can sample from your original random variable. It is generally possible to sample from uniform distributions, so this can often be done. This technique is called [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

As an example, the exponential distribution has c.d.f. $$F_X(x) = 1 - e^{-x/\beta}.$$ The inverse is then $F_X^{-1}(x) = -\beta \ln(1 - x)$. It follows that, if $U$ is a uniform random variable, then $Y = - \beta \ln(1 - U)$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\beta$. The Python numeric library NumPy actually samples from the exponential distribution in this way, as can be seen in their [random sampling source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.c).

Comment: Thanks very much this really makes sense! Also, for all the variables as in the passage, in trying to find the distribution function of $F_{X}(U) $ I get $F_{X}^{-1}(x) $. Does this mean $F_{X}(U)$~$X^{-1}$?

Comment: Well, it means that the c.d.f. of $F_X(U)$ is $F_X^{-1}$. I'm not sure what notation you would use here, since $X^{-1}$ looks like $1/X$.